# Why can't I run java from the command line anymore?

Tags: java, cmd

I've been running java programs from the command line for 5+ years using the same process:

1. javac Program.java
2. java Program

This is suddenly not working.  Compiling works, but when I try to run the program I get an error saying the class cannot be found.

However, now when I type this, it works:

1. javac Program.java
2. java Program.java

This is fine, but when I have a class that extends another, it isn't being found.

Here is how it looks on the command line:

C:\Drive\Java>javac Program.java

C:\Drive\Java>java Program

Error: Could not find or load main class Program
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Program

C:\Drive\Java>java Program.java
Hello World

Is there something I could have done to cause this change?  I noticed it started happening yesterday after a windows update.

Comment: When you run `dir` from `C:/Drive/Java`, do you see a `Program.class` file there?  You would need that to be present in order for Java to run (along with all other dependencies, assuming they exist).

Comment: Yes I do.  The Program.class file is there.

Comment: What is your package you are using for Program.java?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what that means.  To make things as simple as possible, the entire program is just this:

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}

Comment: so there is no package declaration in your code?

Comment: What if you write `java -cp . Program`?

Comment: writing java -cp . Program works!

But why?  And can I change it back?

Answer (score 0):

The Class's name should be exactly the same with the file name, please paste the code or check it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue.  The problem was that I had added a CLASSPATH environmental variable that pointed to my java bin folder and this was causing the behavior.  I deleted it and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you check if your computer system is compatible with your jdk version.
And support? x86 x64